# update database with a ruby function

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a series of folders that all have files I need linked to the database (via there file path).  One option I could do is manually insert all the file paths into my database, however, this can be painful as the number of folders will keep increasing and manual uploading will take too much time.

Is there a way to write a ruby helper function that will search these folders and automatically add the path to the files into a column in my database?

All the file paths have a recognizable pattern, for example:

```
Tel/a_1/poi1/names.csv
Tel/a_2/poi1/names.csv
Tel/a_3/poi1/names.csv
```

I need a function that will occupy a field in my database with the path of each of these `names.csv` files.  Very new to ruby and rails, so any help is greatly appreciated.  Also, please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: start by reading about the file object: http://apidock.com/ruby/File

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should give u all the filenames in the folder, for you to manipulate:

```
Dir["Tel/**/**/*.csv].each do |file|
  * update attribute of your model with the path of the file
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about the [Dir](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Dir.html) object too.

Thats a example to get all files.

Dir["Tel/a_*/poi1/names.csv"] return a Array with path about all files.